# How do you build a campfire that leaves no trace?

Tags: fire, leave-no-trace

Say you're camping in the backcountry where there aren't any developed campsites or fire rings. What methods are there for building a camp fire that will leave absolutely no trace afterwards?

Comment: I"m looking forward to seeing the answers on this one.

Comment: @PaulD Me too, I'm hoping for a variety of answers as well.

Comment: *Absolutely no trace* will be sheer impossible.

Comment: @wills No it isn't. Impractical maybe, but not impossible.

Comment: @ShemSeger maybe something like this? http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/4556/2653

Comment: Are you assuming you can obtain firewood without disturbing the environment, e.g., you're car camping and have brought in firewood in the car? If you're in the backcountry, then you're going to have to gather wood, and that's not going to be LNT.

Comment: @BenCrowell Where I'm from you could take a full cord of firewood out of the woods without anyone noticing. In fact, that's how a lot of people heat their homes for the winter. The availability of firewood will obviously be a factor that will impact whether or not you can make a leave no trace camp fire. It is possible to gather wood without leaving a trace, but it depends a lot on where you are.

Comment: @Wills That's one way of doing it, but I was hoping to uncover more than just a single method with this question.