# Why use a Dakota fire pit?

Tags: fire

While reading [this answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/13637/2199) I ended up watching a couple of youtube videos and heard [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dioShcC5zeA) mentioning a "Dakota fire pit".

I hadn't heard about it before, but could easily find a few images by searching the web:
[image: Dakota fire pit]

Seems pretty straighforward, but the question remains:

- **Why would I build a fire pit like this?**
- **What are the advantages?**

Comment: Getting that tunnel to hold looks easy in the picture.  Not a chance in sandy soil.  Even in clay when the fire dries out the the soil it may collapse.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Efficiency, mostly

- The fire should be able to burn very hot.
- Less fuel is needed (faster cooking).
- Produces less smoke.
- Less susceptible to wind.
- Light is shielded.
- Easy to cover up to extinguish.
- Covering it to remove evidence is easier.
- Support for cookware is easily added (something like green sticks across the top is possible).
- Should produce less sparks and floating cinders (than a surface fire), which would make it safer in dry conditions

### There's always a downside

- The biggest downside is that you still have to dig in the ground [and most likely damage it](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/how-to-make-a-fire-without-burning-the-ground) (*not* a leave no trace fire).
- Should be pretty useful if you've got a permanent camp. But it could be a lot of effort for a one-nighter.

---

Sources: [Modern Survival Blog](http://modernsurvivalblog.com/survival-skills/advantages-of-the-dakota-fire-hole/), [Survival Topics](http://survivaltopics.com/the-dakota-fire-hole/), [@DCShannon](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/11157/dcshannon), [@Liam](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/2766/liam)

Comment: Probably p;retty useful if you've got a permenant camp. A lot of effort for a one nighter. Nice technnique though

Comment: Essentially the same concept as a kiln, but underground. And yes, such a fire would kill the earth around it, it's not a leave no trace fire.